# Ant design table row merge based on data instead of index value

Tags: reactjs, html-table, antd

```
 {
    title: 'Home phone',
    colSpan: 2,
    dataIndex: 'tel',
    render: (value, row, index) => {
      const obj = {
        children: value,
        props: {},
      };
      if (index === 2) {
        obj.props.rowSpan = 2;
      }
      // These two are merged into above cell
      if (index === 3) {
        obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
      }
      if (index === 4) {
        obj.props.colSpan = 0;
      }
      return obj;
    },
  },
```

[image]

In dis example based on index value rowsspan size is decided, can we do that based on previous column data (if there are two John Brown's then row span should be 2)?. So basically we need to decide row span size by sorting rows and comparing row value.

Comment: You can make the option as a function return, and pass the data as param for your customized merge condition

Comment: can u elaborate? didn't get you..

Comment: did u ever find a solution to this? @Hemanthvrm

Comment: sorry i haven't...

Answer (score 2):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bubauz?file=index.js
I can give you an idea with name column, mb it helps you.
If you want to merge Name column:

First of all you need to sort your table data.Then create Set(). And you need clear Set in useEffect().

```
const names = new Set();

{
  title: 'Name',
  rowSpan: 1,
  dataIndex: 'name',
  render: (value, row, index) => {
    const obj = {
      children: value,
      props: {}
    };
    
    if (names.has(value)) {
      obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
    } else {
      const occurCount = tableData.filter((data) => data.name === value).length;
      
      obj.props.rowSpan = count;
      names.add(value);
    }

    return obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Hemanthvrm check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bubauz?file=index.js

Comment: I've got the same problem and I tried applying your code to mine but my column of values disappear when I set obj.prop.rowSpan value to 0. I tried recreating my problem in sandbox project https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-moser-3pk77?file=/src/App.js:306-635

Comment: @mirkovski idk what's wrong in your example, doesn't have time to research it, sorry, but try [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bubauz-sc1scx?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

another way to merge row is using onCell, you should create Set() to save the values merged, and clear it in useEffect.

If the name is existed in Set then return rowSpan equal to zero wil prevent the cell to be rendered. And if the name not existed in Set yet then return the index that the name should be in dataTable

You can read more about onCell in antd doc here: https://ant.design/components/table#table

```
const mergeValue = new Set();

useEffect(() => {
    mergeValue.clear();
},[]);

//The code under is to insert into antd table column

{
  title: 'Name',
  key: 'name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  onCell: (record, index) => {
   if (mergeValue.has(record.name)) {
     return { rowSpan: 0 };
   }else{
     const rowCount = tableData.filter((data) => data.name === record.name).length;
     mergeValue.add(record.name);
     return { rowSpan: rowCount };
   }
    return {};
  },
}
```