# how to mix rowspan and expandable rows in ant design table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use both row span and expandable rows from ant design table component

the target table should look something like this:

[image]

i am using the following code to generate this table:

```
  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Overall',
      colSpan: 4,
      dataIndex: 'metric',
      ellipsis: true,
      fixed: 'left',
      width: 100,
      render: (value, row, index) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {},
        };
        if (index % 8 === 0) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 8;
        } else {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
        }
        return obj;
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'Bucket',
      colSpan: 0,
      dataIndex: 'bucket',
      ellipsis: true,
      fixed: 'left',
      width: 100,
      render: (value, row, index) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {},
        };
        if (index % 2 === 0) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 2;
        } else {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
        }
        return obj;
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'Target',
      colSpan: 0,
      dataIndex: 'target',
      ellipsis: true,
      fixed: 'left',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: 'Overall Value',
      colSpan: 0,
      dataIndex: 'overall_value',
      ellipsis: true,
      fixed: 'left',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: '2019-01-01',
      dataIndex: '2019-01-01',
      ellipsis: true,
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: '2019-01-02',
      dataIndex: '2019-01-02',
      ellipsis: true,
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: '2019-01-03',
      dataIndex: '2019-01-03',
      ellipsis: true,
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: '2019-01-04',
      dataIndex: '2019-01-04',
      ellipsis: true,
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: '2019-01-05',
      dataIndex: '2019-01-05',
      ellipsis: true,
      width: 100,
    },
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      key: '1',
      metric: 'ALBS',
      bucket: 'Overall',
      target: 'Actual',
      overall_value: 4781,
      '2019-01-01': 213,
      '2019-01-02': 21,
      '2019-01-03': 23,
      '2019-01-04': 13,
      '2019-01-05': 35,
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      metric: 'ALBS',
      bucket: 'Overall',
      target: '1 Year Ago',
      overall_value: 4781,
      '2019-01-01': 213,
      '2019-01-02': 21,
      '2019-01-03': 23,
      '2019-01-04': 13,
      '2019-01-05': 35,
      children: [
        {
          key: '3',
          metric: 'ALBS',
          bucket: 'Shanghai',
          target: 'Actual',
          overall_value: 4781,
          '2019-01-01': 213,
          '2019-01-02': 21,
          '2019-01-03': 23,
          '2019-01-04': 13,
          '2019-01-05': 35,
        },
        {
          key: '4',
          metric: 'ALBS',
          bucket: 'Shanghai',
          target: '1 Year Ago',
          overall_value: 4781,
          '2019-01-01': 213,
          '2019-01-02': 21,
          '2019-01-03': 23,
          '2019-01-04': 13,
          '2019-01-05': 35,
        },
        {
          key: '5',
          metric: 'ALBS',
          bucket: 'Peking',
          target: 'Actual',
          overall_value: 4781,
          '2019-01-01': 213,
          '2019-01-02': 21,
          '2019-01-03': 23,
          '2019-01-04': 13,
          '2019-01-05': 35,
        },
        {
          key: '6',
          metric: 'ALBS',
          bucket: 'Peking',
          target: '1 Year Ago',
          overall_value: 4781,
          '2019-01-01': 213,
          '2019-01-02': 21,
          '2019-01-03': 23,
          '2019-01-04': 13,
          '2019-01-05': 35,
        },
        {
          key: '7',
          metric: 'ALBS',
          bucket: 'Canton',
          target: 'Actual',
          overall_value: 4781,
          '2019-01-01': 213,
          '2019-01-02': 21,
          '2019-01-03': 23,
          '2019-01-04': 13,
          '2019-01-05': 35,
        },
        {
          key: '8',
          metric: 'ALBS',
          bucket: 'Canton',
          target: '1 Year Ago',
          overall_value: 4781,
          '2019-01-01': 213,
          '2019-01-02': 21,
          '2019-01-03': 23,
          '2019-01-04': 13,
          '2019-01-05': 35,
        },
      ]
    },
  ];

  const expandable = {
    expandIconColumnIndex: 1,
  };

  return (
    <Table columns={columns} size="small" dataSource={data} expandable={expandable} scroll={{ x: true }} bordered defaultExpandAllRows />
  );
```

the table being generated looks something like this:

[image]

there are several problems with this table:

1. the second column messes up the children, somehow it doesn't realise that first column is rendered already
2. the expand button doesn't get rendered correctly because i am attaching children on (col 2, row 2) instead of (col 2, row 1). but if i attach children on first row, it doesn't realise that every 2 rows should be treated as a group when expanding

any idea how to fix these problems?

Comment: Unfortunately thats not possible i assume,  I was looking for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285411/ant-design-table-row-merge-based-on-data-instead-of-index-value